# Docker Build ERROR: failed to solve / authorize / fetch oauth token connectex: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden

Tags: docker

I tried "docker build -t xpto/xyz:v1.0.0 ." but Docker returns:

ERROR: failed to solve: eclipse-temurin:17-jre-alpine: failed to authorize: failed to fetch oauth token: Post "https://auth.docker.io/token": dial tcp XX.XXX.XX.XX:XXX: connectex: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.

Any ideia of how fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution was docker pull eclipse-temurin:17-jre-alpine and after docker build